# Manipulate checkbox and text box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in mypage,

```
    ....
    <input type="checkbox" title="Warehouse1" name="warehouse[]" id="selectedUser_1" class="select_checkbox" rel="warhouse_1" value="23">
    <input type="checkbox" title="Warehouse2" name="warehouse[]" id="selectedUser_2" class="select_checkbox" rel="warhouse_2" value="24">
    .....
    //text box to enter current stock for the above warehouses
    <input type="text" style="" name="current_stock[]" value="10" id="current_st_1" class="validtxt">
    <input type="text" style="" name="current_stock[]" value="11" id="current_st_2" class="validtxt">
    .....
<input type="button" id="check_warehouse_qty" name="check_warehouse_qty" value="OK">
```

Here when i click button i need to store repective checkbox value with textbox . for example
i need to get `23_10,24_11` . so that i can assign in hidden textbox and do further manipulation.
kindly advice on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd want to do something like this:

```
$('#check_warehouse_qty').click(function() {

    $('.select_checkbox').each(function() {

        var val = $(this).val();  // "23"

        var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('selectedUser_', '');

        val += $('#current_st_' + id).val(); // "23_10"

        // store 'val' in some hidden field
        $('hidden_field_' + id).val(val);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand how you want to move your values around but here's a shot.

You can set the value of a form field with:

```
$('#inputId').val(newVal);
```

So in your case something like this would move the current_st_1 value to the selectedUser_1 value:

```
$('#selectedUser_1').val($('#current_st_1').val());
```

If you want to concatenate the values you can use:

```
$('#selectedUser_1').val($('#selectedUser_1').val() + '_' + $('#current_st_1').val());
```

Here is a link to the jQuery API docs for the val() function:
http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

To get/set the value you should be able to use .val(), for example, something like:

```
$('#current_st_1').val($('#selectedUser_1').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('#check_warehouse_qty').click(function(e){

            //check if first checkbox is ticked
            if ($('#selectedUser_1').attr('checked')) {
                //checks if value was already put in
                if($('#current_st_1').val().indexOf($('#selectedUser_1').val()+'_') == -1){
                    //if it was not then set the value
                    $('#current_st_1').val($('#selectedUser_1').val()+'_'+$('#current_st_1').val());
                }
            }
            else{
                //remove value if unchecked
                $('#current_st_1').val($('#current_st_1').val().replace($('#selectedUser_1').val()+'_',''));
            }

            //check if second checkbox is ticked
            if ($('#selectedUser_2').attr('checked')) {
                //checks if value was already put in
                if($('#current_st_2').val().indexOf($('#selectedUser_2').val()+'_') == -1){
                    //if it was not then set the value
                    $('#current_st_2').val($('#selectedUser_2').val()+'_'+$('#current_st_2').val());
                }
            }
            else{
                //remove value if unchecked
                $('#current_st_2').val($('#current_st_2').val().replace($('#selectedUser_2').val()+'_',''));
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```